# Is it possible that same IP shows up in Gmail even if the hacker is reading my emails?

Tags: ip, gmail

Is it possible that same IP shows up by clicking in the extreme downright corner  "Details” button in Gmail even if the hacker is accessing / reading my Gmail. If Yes, how to prevent this.

Comment: The hacker is in your house! Run you fool!

Answer (score 2):

Although you did not provide that much information,
the only way the hacker reading your emails would have the same IP as you is if he is accessing your email through your computer/network.

A few things you can do:

- Make sure no one is on your WiFi other than authorized devices (as in devices you expect to be connected).
- Run an anti virus scan to see if any malware is installed on your computer
- Make sure any remote tools you are using are secure (do they all have a strong username and password?).
- Make sure it is not anyone from your family/friends that are in your house or even on your computer.

If after doing all the above the hacker still can access your email, using a device you know is clean reset your email password and then restore your computer.

**Note:** If your computer is in fact infected you should assume the hacker has all your credentials from any site/services you use.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bubble Hacker's answer, it's also possible if your ISP uses a [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), which would mean your public IP is shared with other ISP clients. The only way I know to avoid this is to change ISP.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a proxy/VPN instead of going through the (relatively) complex process of changing your ISP?

Comment: @Krazor if that proxy/VPN guarantees you a unique IP. Otherwise, you could imagine the other user knows you've switched to that proxy/VPN (though I'll agree that if they have that kind of knowledge, you probably have some kind of malware on your system)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I think it's very unlikely that they'd know. And if they did, you're screwed anyways. Also, the hacker would have to subscribe to the same VPN as you do, and it's not necessarily possible to find the VPN just by knowing one of the exit nodes. I liked your answer for that heads up on ip-sharing anyways. :)